# Simple select from generic list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list:

`List<Product> allProducts = new List<Product>();`

The products can have the same displayname, but different URL:s. What i would like to do is to get all the urls for each product.

```
foreach (Product p in allProducts.Distinct().ToList())
    {
        string displayname = p.GetDisplayName();
        string url = p.GetPublishedUrls()[0];
    }
```

But im stuck here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean you have products A,B,C, where A has URLS (A1, A2, A3), B has URLs (B2, B3, B4, B5), C has URLs (C2, C3) ? And, what are you looking for as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GroupBy:

```
foreach (var productGroup in allProducts.GroupBy(p => p.GetDisplayName()) {
    # productGroup.Key is the display name
    # and productGroup enumerates all the products for the display name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

```
List<string> allUrls = allProducts.SelectMany(p => p.GetPublishedUrls()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give SelectMany a go - this should return an IEnumerable if I read your code snippet correctly.

```
IEnumerable<string> publishedUrls = allProducts.SelectMany(p => p.GetPublishedUrls());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand your question, but if you'r trying to creat a list that each of its items has the product display name and urls, here's the code:

var res = from p in products.AsQueryable()
                      select new { ProductName = p.Name, ProductUrls = p.Urls };

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
 class Product
 {
     public string DisplayName;
     public string URL;
 }


 List<Product> allProducts = new List<Product>();

 allProducts.Add(new Product { DisplayName = "A", URL = "A1" });
 allProducts.Add(new Product { DisplayName = "A", URL = "A2" });
 allProducts.Add(new Product { DisplayName = "A", URL = "A3" });

 allProducts.Add(new Product { DisplayName = "B", URL = "B1" });
 allProducts.Add(new Product { DisplayName = "B", URL = "B3" });

 var pGroups = from p in allProducts
               group p by p.DisplayName into g
               select new { DisplayName = g.Key, URLList = g };

 foreach (var p in pGroups)
 {
       Console.WriteLine("Product Name: " + p.DisplayName);
       foreach (var u in p.URLList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("  URL: " + u.URL);
       }
 }
```

Output:

```
Product Name: A
  URL: A1
  URL: A2
  URL: A3
Product Name: B
  URL: B1
  URL: B3
```